# Improve Query Performance of This SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I would like to improve performance of this query, which now takes 13 seconds to return the result.

The main table has more than 2,000,000 records. The result contains only 34 records. The tables have indexes on `r.date_gps`.

```
SELECT
    r.id,
    c.name,
    CONCAT(v.title, '', v.plaque) AS title,v.type_vehicle,
    r.sn,
    r.lat,
    r.lng,
    r.direction,
    r.date_db,
    r.date_gps,
    r.volt_main,
    r.speed,
    r.ing,
    t.sat_fix,
    r.sat
FROM registers r
JOIN trackers t ON t.cod = r.sn
JOIN installations i ON t.id = i.trackers_id
JOIN vehicles v ON v.id = i.vehicles_id
JOIN clients c ON c.id = v.clients_id
WHERE r.date_gps = (
    SELECT MAX(rr.date_gps) FROM registers rr WHERE r.sn = rr.sn
)
AND c.management_id = p_management
GROUP BY r.sn
ORDER BY r.date_gps DESC;
```

Comment: Did you check explain plan?

Comment: Please add query execution plan to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `Mysql` does not support `Row_Number` window functions

Try re-writing the `sub-query` to `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT r.id, 
       c.NAME, 
       Concat(v.title, '', v.plaque) AS title, 
       v.type_vehicle, 
       r, 
       sn, 
       .....
FROM   registers r 
       JOIN trackers t 
         ON t.cod = r.sn 
       JOIN installations i 
         ON t.id = i.trackers_id 
       JOIN vehicles v 
         ON v.id = i.vehicles_id 
       JOIN clients c 
         ON c.id = v.clients_id 
            AND c.management_id = p_management 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(rr.date_gps) AS date_gps, 
                          sn 
                   FROM   registers rr
                   GROUP BY sn) a 
               ON r.sn = a.sn 
                  AND r.date_gps = a.date_gps 
GROUP  BY r.sn 
ORDER  BY r.date_gps DESC;
```

Comment: It is unclear to me how aggregating the entire `registers` table instead of looking up only the matching rows will improve performance.  It will be interesting to hear back from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at improving performance for queries, the place to start is the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses:

```
FROM registers r JOIN 
     trackers t
     ON t.cod = r.sn JOIN
     installations i
     ON t.id = i.trackers_id JOIN
     vehicles v
     ON v.id = i.vehicles_id JOIN
     clients c
     ON c.id = v.clients_id
WHERE r.date_gps = (SELECT MAX(rr.date_gps) FROM registers rr WHERE r.sn = rr.sn
                   ) AND
      c.management_id = p_management
GROUP BY r.sn
ORDER BY r.date_gps DESC;
```

These suggest indexes on `clients(management_id, id)`, `vehicles(clients_id, id)`, `installations(vehicles_id, trackers_id)`, `trackers(trackers_id, cod)`,  and `registers(sn, date_gps)`.

This will (essentially) encourage the optimizer to implement the joins starting with the `clients` table, filtering on `management_id`.  The joins will then use only the indexes and this part of the query should be quite fast.  Of course, if you have thousands or millions of matches, then the `GROUP BY` will still slow the query down (and MySQL has few options for improving the performance of `GROUP BY`).

Answer (score 0):

To speed up your Query with such bunch of data, you have to shrink your maintable at first. Sometimes are 2 Queries better then one.

Try to get your WHERE Data first

```
SELECT MAX(rr.date_gps) FROM registers rr WHERE r.sn = rr.sn
```

And then use the result so add it to the main Query.

Here it is also possible to use a Subquery first, before you join to the other tables.

for example

```
SELECT registers.*
FROM (
    SELECT registers.id
    FROM registers
    WHERE <My WHERE Conditions>
) AS registers_sub

INNER JOIN registers 
ON registers_sub.id = registers.id
```

and then do the rest of your query. So you got a little set of data when you do much joins and groups.

And the last hint, dont use * in SELECT segment if you dont need everything ;D

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help in trying to better query performance.

VR46, had rewritten the query to this format, but the main bank continued slow.

ZFNerd, had also divided into two queries, occurs the same slowness.
Gordon Linoff, the fields are already indexed.

I have a query using another field to get the most current, but it was not what I wanted, because some equipment first send the current data after the oldest and thus end up having trouble finding the most current record.
But some can be configured to send first the earliest.
I think for now I'll use this format for the update is fast and the problems will be minimal.

```
SELECT c.name,CONCAT(v.title,' ',v.plaque) AS title,v.type_vehicle,r.id,
r.sn,r.lat,r.lng, r.direction,r.date_db,r.date_gps,r.volt_main,r.speed,
r.ign,r.sat_fix,r.sat
FROM registers r
JOIN trackers t ON t.cod = r.sn
JOIN installations i ON t.id = i.trackers_id
JOIN vehicles v ON v.id = i.vehicles_id
JOIN clients c ON c.id = v.clients_id
JOIN (
    SELECT rr.sn, MAX(rr.id) AS id FROM registers rr GROUP BY sn
) AS L2 ON r.sn = L2.sn AND r.id = L2.id
AND c.management_id = p_management
GROUP BY r.sn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the other queries might help via select max() group by, it might be better for you to go a different route.  It appears you are tracking vehicles moving goods of some type and want the latest location at any given point.

You might be better by updating your "Trackers" table and adding a column for LastGPSDate.  Then, via a trigger when inserting into your Date_GPS table, issue an update to the corresponding Trackers.LastGPSDate where the COD = the gps.sn you are inserting from (based on your join clause).  Then your query would be simplified down to

```
SELECT
      r.id,
      c.name,
      CONCAT(v.title, '', v.plaque) AS title,v.type_vehicle,
      r.sn,
      r.lat,
      r.lng,
      r.direction,
      r.date_db,
      r.date_gps,
      r.volt_main,
      r.speed,
      r.ing,
      t.sat_fix,
      r.sat
   FROM 
      clients c 
         JOIN vehicles v 
            ON c.id = v.clients_id
            JOIN installations i 
              ON v.id = i.vehicles_id
              join trackers t 
                 ON i.trackers_id = t.id
                 JOIN registers r 
                    ON t.cod = r.sn
                   AND t.LastGPSDate = r.date_gps
   WHERE
      c.management_id = p_management
   ORDER BY 
      t.LastGPSDate DESC;
```

I reversed the ordering of the tables to better match what you are looking for.  Start with ONE client with specific where via the management ID.  Then, only their vehicles to installations, trackers and finally registers.

I would then suggest the following indexes
    table          index
    clients        ( management_id, id )
    vehicles       ( id, clients_id )
    installations  ( trackers_id, vehicles_id )
    trackers       ( LastGPSDate, cod, id, sat_fix )
    registers      ( sn, date_gps )

Due to the join clause specifically limiting for one management ID, I have put that into the first position of the index.

So, of the 2+ million records, the BULK of your data could be of 20, 30, 100 different management IDs, why generate a MAX applied to ALL registers every time you run it.  By stamping the date/time once each time via a trigger, you get your data quicker and only for those clients you want at that moment.